# Prevent default doesnt work when enter key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

my asp.net control looks like this;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" Text="Exit" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" />
```

and js event;

```
 $("#btnLogOut").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(event.keyCode);
        $("#btnLogOut").preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
});
```

On the page, when I pressed enter key, it triggers btnLogOut button. To prevent this,
I wrote above js event. alert says that keyCode is 13 but it's not preventing click function and I log out.

How Can I fix this? This especially occurs in IE

Edit: `event.preventDefault` not working also.

Comment: i think you need to do `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is a method of the Event object (`event`) so you need to call it on that: `event.preventDefault()`.

However, in the `keyup` event the key **has already been handled** so there is no point in blocking the event. Do it in `keydown` instead.

Comment: It's working with keydown, for keyup not working in my case except I have to change the button type to button, not submit

Answer (score 4):

You can't cancel in the `keyup` fase, you *can* in `keydown`.

And use `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

The [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is used with event object

```
$("#btnLogOut").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert(event.keyCode);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `event.preventDefault();` instead of calling `preventDefault()` on the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$("#btnLogOut").preventDefault();` to `event.preventDefault();`